# Application domain showing different ip addresses in different regions

Tags: dns

I have an issue regarding my web app domain. I have shifted app from GoDaddy server to AWS server using route53 currently, it shows different IP addresses at different regions, is there any solution?

Comment: Can you provide more information about what you did? Is it that you have provisioned a single EC2 and use Route53 to map the DNS to it and you see multiple IPs?

Comment: I have shifted domain using Route53 by copying nameservers from GoDaddy to AWS server

Comment: So you still usimg hosting from Godaddy or in AWS EC2?

Comment: currently using AWS hosting

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure that your domain is using the AWS route 53 assigned name servers, you could check by doing this:

```
$ dig yourdmain.tld ns +trace +short
```

You could also use `dig` to check a specific record type for example:

```
$ dig www.yourdomain.tld
```

If no type argument is supplied, `dig` will perform a lookup for an A record

Verify also that you don't have duplicated records (IP's) on your zone, also could be happening that the change has just been made and changes are been propagated.

You could also use this site to check your DNS configuration: https://intodns.com/

Comment: I have checked my domain on https://www.whatsmydns.net, its showing different IP addresses for different zones like the USA, Canada having different IPs. I want all IPs to be same.

Comment: could you share your domain, are you using a CND by any chance? what are the name servers shown when you use https://intodns.com ?

Comment: I am using groups99.com domain.

Comment: you have other NS entries, try to remove  `ns9.bravehost.com` and  
`ns10.bravehost.com` only keep the ones containing the string `awsdns` seems that you already did, but your domain still propagating, the output of `+trace` don't show the `bravehost.com` domains